# Add-SPSolution Invalid character in the given encoding

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

having a problem running Add-SPSolution .wsp.  get the following error:  Invalid character in the given encoding. line ##, position ##.  Invalid data.

we have 6 dev servers dedicated to sharepoint development.  this is happening on just one of the servers.

Comment: can you share the code?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using powershell script just check that during copying script files from one server to another sometimes it may happen that it inserts invalid character in the scripts.

So please check n remove those characters and it will work fine.

Comment: found exactly where the issue is.  the package template xml file is having the issue.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
</Feature>

Comment: at this time not sure how to handle this issue, any thoughts would be helpful.